# CustomView UIBarButtonItem works for all phones other than iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I created a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view using the following code (I specify the size of the `profileImageButton` frame to have dimensions 40x40).

```
let profileImageButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
profileImageButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
profileImageButton.setImage(imageCache.getProfileImage(), for: .normal)
profileImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
profileImageButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
profileImageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileImageButton)
```

On most devices, the view has a 40x40 frame. However, when I run it on the iPhone 6s, it looks a bit rectangular. So I printed out its frame in the debug hierarchy feature of Xcode. The result I get is: `frame = (0 0; 50 44)`, which I assume means that the frame has dimensions 50x44. Therefore, my question is why doesn't the iPhone 6s keep the specified 40x40 size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 11, the size of a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view is determined by the *internal constraints* of the custom view. You have not provided any internal constraints, so all bets are off; you have not put yourself in charge of the bar button item's size. To do so, give `profileImageButton` a width constraint and a height constraint.

Comment: would that entail just setting its width and height anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto matt's answer, I needed to also add these three lines of code for use in iOS 11:

```
profileImageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
profileImageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
profileImageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```